# How to filter Contacts on CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP while getting contacts from Phonebook Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

In my application i want to get contact from phone and  i want to filter it on `CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP` please help me how can it possible?

**my query is :**

```
 Cursor crr = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,                       
 new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA_VERSION,                                
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + " = ?",
                        new String[]{" > '1455531760472' "}, null);
```

but this query return 0 raw count. please show me is it right way for filter or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put my own question's answer :

```
Cursor crr = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,                       
 new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA_VERSION,                                
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + " > ?",
                        new String[]{"1455531760472"}, null);
```